# Vb.net вызов события

Tags: c#, vb.net

Пишу на VB.Net. Есть checkbox. Как в событии checkedchanged или checkedstatechanged вызывать событие combobox.selectedindexchanged?

в С# это делал так:

```
 CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender; // приводим отправителя к элементу типа CheckBox
            if (checkBox.Checked == true)
            {
                chkbx_codes.Click += new EventHandler(combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
            
            combobox1.Refresh();
```

Второй вопрос: как в vb.net сделать аналог `combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged += combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged;`  ?

Пробовал онлайн конверторы,но на код ругается.

Пример того,как они преобразовали код:

```
Private Sub chkbx_codes_CheckStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim checkBox As CheckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)

    If checkBox.Checked = True Then
        chkbx_codes.Click += New EventHandler(combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged)
   
    End If

    combobox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Весь вопрос сводится к тому,как вызывать в одном событии другие.
Пробовал варианты с форумов,конвертер(код выше),но не сработал ни один.

Comment: Так вам нужно **вызвать** событие или **добавить** его?

Comment: `Refresh` - опять ненужный вызов рефреш. Постоянно лепят его вызов куда попало. Я зверею при виде этого! Да, конечно, у этого метода плохое название, но ведь можно почитать описание, что он делает? Вы разве рисуете в событии `ComboBox.Paint`? Только в этом случае может понадобиться вызов `Refresh`. Во всех остальных случаях он бесполезен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге сам же нашел ответ на свой второй вопрос. Помогло это:

```
AddHandler combobox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf combobox_SelectedIndexChanged
```